# Node.js HTTPS server wont send data

Tags: node.js, openssl

I've two node.js servers: one is http, and the other is https

```
//HTTP server
http.createServer(function(request,response){
    unifiedServer(request,response);
}).listen(config.httpPort,function(){
    console.log('listening at port ' + config.httpPort)
});

//HTTPS server
var httpsServerOptions = {
    'key': fs.readFileSync('./https/key.pem'),
    'cert': fs.readFileSync('./https/cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(httpsServerOptions,function(request,response){
    unifiedServer(request,response);
}).listen(config.httpsPort,function(){
    console.log('listening at port ' + config.httpsPort)
});

//Instantiating the servers
var unifiedServer = function(request,response){....
```

When I run it, it will console.log `listening at port 3000` (http) and `listening at port 3001` (https)

3000 works just fine but.. When going into 3001 I get `This page isn’t working`

I've checked in case the key and certifications might be the problem, but as far as I can see they are doing their work just fine.

Any insights into this problem are appreciated

Comment: What URL are you using for the 3001 server?  What is the exact error you get?

Comment: Please answer the questions i asked in my previous comment.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm using `http://localhost:3001/home`

Comment: You need https on the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `https` on the URL to the 3001 server:

`https://localhost:3001/home`